# most economical path for sewer design

Tags: genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

Can you help me in Establishing an Optimization Model for Sewer System Layout
with Applied Genetic Algorithm

Comment: Help you how?  What do you have so far?

Comment: Is this homework, or do you work for a city? I hope it's the former.

Comment: Probably beyond your capabilities

Comment: need way more info than just that pal

Answer (score 1):

Not really a programming problem, there is a "integer programming algorithm for optimizing pipe sizes and slopes" [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1752-1688.1971.tb05911.x/abstract)

Comment: I understand that genetics algo / ACO algo can solve this problem. Which one is better in this case?

Comment: @Anshul you need to provide way more info for people to be able to help you out. And be more specific, not just 'please solve it for me'